# Retornar valores utilizando Dialog's

Tags: java, android, alertdialog

Tenho o seguinte método `dialogConfirme` no qual contém um dialogo customizado declarado como `public static` para retornar um valor do tipo `boolean`. A questão do `static` é para que eu possa chamar de qualquer classe usando um `context` como mostra abaixo:

```
static boolean flag = false;

public static boolean dialogConfirme(final Context context, String mensagem) {

    final Dialog myDialog = new Dialog(context);
    myDialog.setContentView(R.layout.material_dialog_exit);
    myDialog.setTitle(mensagem);

    Button btnSim = (Button) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.btnOption1);
    btnSim.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            flag = true;
            myDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    Button btnNao = (Button) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.btnOption2);
    btnNao.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            flag = false;
            myDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    myDialog.show();
    return flag;
}
```

#### Dúvida

Tendo um seguinte condição numa outra classe e gostaria que o valor retornasse no momento em que eu clicasse no botão:

```
boolean dialog = dialogConfirme;

if(dialog){

//retornou verdadadeiro ..

} else {

//retornou falso

}
```

Porém, antes de clicar em qualquer botão dentro do método do diálogo, eu já obtenho um retorno. Teria como obter o retorno somente no momento em que eu clicar nos botões `btnSim` ou `btnNao`? Como? Seria uma "má prática" seguir este pensamento?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O Dialog é apresentado de forma assíncrona, o seu resultado(função do botão escolhido para o fechar) só pode ser obtido recorrendo a um *callback*:

Declare uma *interface*:

```
public interface DialogResultListener{

    void onResult(boolean result);
}
```

Faça o método `dialogConfirme()` receber um argumento que implemente a interface, ele será usado para informar o resultado do Dialog:

```
public static void dialogConfirme(final Context context, String mensagem,
                                  DialogResultListener listener) {

    final Dialog myDialog = new Dialog(context);
    myDialog.setContentView(R.layout.material_dialog_exit);
    myDialog.setTitle(mensagem);

    Button btnSim = (Button) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.btnOption1);
    btnSim.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //Notifique o resultado
            listener.onResult(true);
            myDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    Button btnNao = (Button) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.btnOption2);
    btnNao.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //Notifique o resultado
            listener.onResult(false);
            myDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    myDialog.show();
}
```

Use assim:

```
dialogConfirme(context, "Confirme por favor", new DialogResultListener(){

    public void onResult(boolean result){
        if(result){

        //Botão SIM

        } else {

        //Botão NÃO

        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Parece interessante! Já vou testar!

Comment: Não sua opinião @ramaral, você vê isso como uma "boa prática" praticar ou existe maneiras mais viáveis?

Comment: É uma prática usual para receber valores assincronamente ou para personalizar comportamento. Por exemplo, o método poderia receber uma interface com dois métodos, um a ser executado quando o botão SIM for escolhido e outro para o botão NÃO. O comportamento de cada botão poderá ser personalizada em cada utilização do método.

Comment: Se existem "maneiras mais viáveis"? Neste caso, chamada a um método, não vejo outra possibilidade.

Comment: Funcionou certinho @ramaral... a minha outra dúvida era a questão se é mesmo viável fazer esse tipo de programação, verificando retorno do diálogo. Mas como você disse, também não vejo nada demais usar o método desta forma. Eu uso esse dialogo pelo menos umas 7 vezes no meu código, no entanto quando clico no sim, tenho que fazer ações diferentes e até então não estava conseguindo resolver e economizar código. Obrigado pela ajuda. Abraços.

Answer (score 0):

na linha

```
myDialog.show();
```

esta executando o botão mesmo se não tiver clique.
logo que vc instancia o objeto ele executa isso
ponha este cod dentro das funções de clique que resolve.

Comment: Isso não resolver o problema!

Comment: ele continua executando ?

Comment: eu acho que o problema esta na sua forma de utilização. voce cria um objeto que retorna no momento da instancia um valor. por que você não cria a função do botão exibindo o dialogo ? e setando a variável flag?
me desculpe não compreendi inteiramente o que acontece se você puder explicar o que esta fazendo colocando as outras classes envolvidas ajuda mais.

Comment: É que estou chamando este método com o diálogo em várias classes sempre com essa decisão. Se eu clicar  sim faça algo, se eu clicar não, não faça nada. Mas aí quando chamo o método dentro já do if, ele já retorna sem eu clicar no botao.

Comment: sim poios vc instacia o objeto e na hora da intancia ele ja retorna 2 coisas sem que você faça nada
o myDialog.show(); e o return flag;
tenta setar a flag como false dentro da classe e nao utiliza static